# Which version of Ruby do I need for Rails 5.2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to install the latest LTS version of Rails (5.2.3 at the time of writing)
https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2019/3/28/Rails-5-2-3-has-been-released/

Which version of Ruby do I need for Rails 5.2.3?

Comment: Rails 5 requires ruby 2.2.2 :https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#ruby-versions

Comment: Why the downvotes? I wasn't able to find a Ruby version specified anywhere in the Rails documentation..

Comment: Note, you can't use Ruby 3 on Rails 5.2 (at the time of writing). See here for the Rails Core discussion: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40938

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails 5 requires minimum 2.2.2, but you'll be perfectly fine on latest stable 2.6.3 (at the time of writing)

Comment: Note, you can't use Ruby 3 on Rails 5.2 (at the time of writing). See here for the Rails Core discussion: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40938